# Android Notification bigLargeIcon: Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match

Tags: android

I am tryting to display a large image in the notification. I am following [the docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded#image-style). But, the IDE is showing the error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
private fun getNotificationBuilder(): NotificationCompat.Builder {
    // this intent opens the MainActivity when the user taps on the notification
    val intentNotification = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntentNotification = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        exampleNotificationID,
        intentNotification,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        context.resources,
        R.drawable.puppy
    )

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context.applicationContext, exampleChannelID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chair)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentNotification)
        .setLargeIcon(myBitmap)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(myBitmap)
            .bigLargeIcon(null)
        )

    return builder
}
```

These are the improts:

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Try `bigLargeIcon(null as Icon?)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally the `BigPictureStyle` API would allow you to say "no large icon, #kthxbye" without passing `null` to a function, let alone one with multiple `null`-capable overloads.

Peeking at the source suggests that it doesn't matter which of the two overloads you wind up calling, so add a cast to one of them:

```kotlin
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context.applicationContext, exampleChannelID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chair)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentNotification)
        .setLargeIcon(myBitmap)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(myBitmap)
            .bigLargeIcon(null as Icon?)
        )
```

(you could use `Bitmap?`, but that's two characters longer )